# uninitialized constant Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, gmaps4rails

I've setup everything according to [README](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) and here's my model

```
class Building
  include Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid

  acts_as_gmappable :lat => 'location[0]', :lng => 'location[1]',
                  :address => "address", :normalized_address => "full_address",
                  :msg => "Sorry, not even Google could figure out where that is"
  field :gmaps,              :type => Boolean

  field :address,            :type => String, :default => ""            
  field :city,               :type => String, :default => ""
  field :province,           :type => String, :default => ""
  field :country,            :type => String, :default => ""
  field :postal_code,        :type => Integer
  field :location,           :type => Array, spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }

  ## Building index
  index({location: "2d"})

  def full_address
    "#{address}, #{city}, #{province}, #{country}, #{postal_code}"
  end

  def gmaps4rails_address
    full_address
  end
end
```

the controller

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@building) do |building, marker|
  marker.lat building.location[0]
  marker.lng building.location[1]
end
```

and the view

```
= gmaps4rails( "markers" => { "data" => @hash.to_json, "options" => { "draggable" => true }})
```

when I access the control, gives me "uninitialized constant Gmaps4rails::ActsAsGmappable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is not](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/search?q=ActsAsGmappable&ref=cmdform) a `ActsAsGmappable` module/class defined in the gem, hence the error.

It seems that it was removed in newer versions of the gem. Try removing that line and see if everything works.

Comment: undefined method `gmaps4rails' for #<#<Class:0xb5504680>:0x27e3100>. red highlight on the view

Comment: There isn't a `gmaps4rails` method for your views. Where did you get that from? Read the [wiki](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki) and the [examples](https://github.com/JonKernPA/gmaps)

Comment: I found some tuts out there using `gmaps()` or `gmaps4rails()` in view, I'll start again with @apneadiving examples. Thx guys